# vb.net I got (Unable to read data from the transport connection) error message from socket

Tags: vb.net, sockets

I'm trying to use a non-synchronous connection server on the client, but occasionally I get an error message on the client. How can I solve the problem?

How to change to callback?

Error code :

> unable to read data from the transport connection the connection was
>   closed
>
> at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   at TFD_SoftPhone.MD_Function.ConnectionInfo.DoReadData(IAsyncResult
>   result)

```
Public Class ConnectionInfo

    Private _AppendMethod As Action(Of String)
    Private _Client As TcpClient
    Private _Stream As NetworkStream
    Private _LastReadLength As Integer
    Private _Buffer(5120) As Byte

    Public ReadOnly Property AppendMethod As Action(Of String)
        Get
            Return _AppendMethod
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property Client As TcpClient
        Get
            Return _Client
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property Stream As NetworkStream
        Get
            Return _Stream
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property LastReadLength As Integer
        Get
            Return _LastReadLength
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub New(address As IPAddress, port As Integer, append As Action(Of String))

        _AppendMethod = append
        _Client = New TcpClient
        Try
            _Client.SendTimeout = 45000
            _Client.ReceiveTimeout = 45000
            _Client.Connect(address, port)
            _Stream = _Client.GetStream
        Catch ex As Exception

            If _Client.Connected Then _Client.Close()
            If Not IsNothing(_Client) Then _Client = Nothing
            If Not IsNothing(_Stream) Then _Stream = Nothing
        End Try

    End Sub


    Public Sub AwaitData()

        Try
            If Not IsNothing(_Stream) Then
                _Stream.ReadTimeout = 45000
                _Stream.WriteTimeout = 45000
                _Stream.BeginRead(_Buffer, 0, _Buffer.Length, AddressOf DoReadData, Me)
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

    End Sub


    Public Sub Close()

        If _Client IsNot Nothing Then _Client.Close()
        _Client = Nothing
        _Stream = Nothing

    End Sub


    Private Sub DoReadData(result As IAsyncResult)

        Dim info As ConnectionInfo = CType(result.AsyncState, ConnectionInfo)

        Try
            If info._Stream IsNot Nothing AndAlso info._Stream.CanRead Then
                info._LastReadLength = info._Stream.EndRead(result)
                ReDim Preserve _Buffer(info._LastReadLength - 1)
                If info._LastReadLength > 0 Then
                    Dim message As String = Encoding.GetEncoding("Big5").GetString(info._Buffer)
                    info._AppendMethod(message)
                    ReDim Preserve _Buffer(5120)
                Else

                End If
                info.AwaitData()
            Else

            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            info._LastReadLength = -1
            info._AppendMethod(ex.Message)
        End Try

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: @ jmcilhinney Thanks for the response, this problem arises from time to time, sometimes it is fully executed, sometimes it will generate an exception. I am looking for possible solutions. I have to use the callback method to ensure the normal operation of sending and receiving.

Comment: The above code, how to change to callback?